# Symfony - Use Apache ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, symfony, errordocument

I want to replace symfony's Error template with apache ErrorDocument.

I have following conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost-de
ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All 
  ErrorDocument 404 /staticErrorPage.html
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /kontakt "/var/www/html/contact/web"
Alias /skin "/var/www/html/skin"

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/skin/(.{7})/(.*) /skin/$2

SetEnv locale de_DE
</VirtualHost>
```

My Symfony application is under "/var/www/html/contact/". When i enter a not existing page like "localhost-de/foo" i am getting the content of my html page.
But when i enter a not existing page like "localhost-de/kontakt/foo" i am always getting the content of symfony/twig page.

I know that i can override twig template but i dont want it this way. Any ideas how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The ErrorDocument is used only for the Directory you specified. You should enclose ErrorDocument in a Location or LocationMatch directive. Read apache documentation for more details.